# Proof environment help needed

Tags: amsmath, theorems, amsthm

I have a bit of an issue that I want to resolve. The issue here is that I want the next line in the proof environment to also be bolded and so on, that is consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, welsh, english, a4paper]{report}
\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem,url,fancyref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem*{corollary*}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\expandafter\let\expandafter\oldproof\csname\string\proof\endcsname
\let\oldendproof\endproof
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{%
  \oldproof[\Large \color{red}{\textbf{Proof}}]%
}{\oldendproof}

%Removing the punctuation from Proof environment and, note environment is the correct spelling of that word.
\usepackage{etoolbox} % etoolbox defines the command 'AtBeginEnvironment'
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\let\@addpunct\@gobble}
\makeatother



\title{LaTeX document for testing and faster compilations prior to organizing into other documents}
\author{Faycal Kilali\thanks{"It is not knowledge, but the act of learning, not possession but the act of getting there, which grants the greatest enjoyment." - Carl Friedrich Gauss}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}






\section{Placeholder section}

                \begin{theorem}\label{thm:9.2}
                    If a connected plane graph has v vertices, e edges and f faces, then \begin{gather}
                        v - e + f = 1 \label{thm:9.2:1}
                    \end{gather} 
                \end{theorem}

\begin{proof}{Proof of \Autoref{thm:9.2}}
    Here is the statement p(n) we are going to try to prove by induction: \\ p(n): every connected plane graph with n edges satisfies the formula \(v - n + f = 1\). 

Notice that p(n) is a statement about lots of plane graphs. p(1) says that every connected plane graph with 1 edge satisfies the formula; there is only one such graph:

\end{proof}
```

This is how it'll look like: [image]

But I want the big red bolded letters of "proof" to also affect the style of the next part that says "Proof of theorem 1.1", how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to redefine `proof` with a mandatory argument.

```
\NewCommandCopy{\oldproof}{\proof}
\NewCommandCopy{\endoldproof}{\endproof}

\renewenvironment{proof}[1]
 {\oldproof[\Large\bfseries\color{red}#1]}
 {\endoldproof}
```

If your LaTeX is older than 2020-10-01, you need to load the `letltxmacro` package and use

```
\LetLtxMacro{\oldproof}{\proof}
\LetLtxMacro{\endoldproof}{\endproof}
```

instead of the `\NewCommandCopy` command.

Here's an edited version of the relevant part of the document. I removed the title part that's not needed for the example.

Math formulas should be *always* be typed in as such. A single equation should not use `gather`.

There is no `\Autoref`, that I changed into `\autoref`. You didn't load `xcolor` and `hyperref`. You also passed options to `babel` without loading it. And if you say `english` among the options to `\documentclass` there's no point in passing again the same option.

```
\documentclass[10pt, welsh, english, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem,url,fancyref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % etoolbox defines the command 'AtBeginEnvironment'
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem*{corollary*}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\NewCommandCopy{\oldproof}{\proof}
\NewCommandCopy{\oldendproof}{\endproof}

\renewenvironment{proof}[1]
 {\oldproof[\Large\bfseries\color{red}#1]}
 {\oldendproof}

%Removing the punctuation from proof environment
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\let\@addpunct\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Placeholder section}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:9.2}
If a connected plane graph has $v$ vertices, $e$ edges and $f$ faces, then
\begin{equation}
v - e + f = 1 \label{thm:9.2:1}
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}{Proof of \autoref{thm:9.2}}
Here is the statement \(p(n)\) we are going to try to prove by induction:
\begin{quote}
\(p(n)\): every connected plane graph with $n$ edges satisfies the formula \(v - n + f = 1\). 
\end{quote}
Notice that \(p(n)\) is a statement about lots of plane graphs. 
\(p(1)\) says that every connected plane graph with one edge satisfies the formula; 
there is only one such graph:
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you really want to punch your readers in their eye?

Comment: Hey um, I don't wanna remake the question but do you think it'd be possible for you to show me how to make it look more like this? https://i.imgur.com/zhlRLWj.png

Note that I'd much prefer if I don't re-define the actual \proof environment for that, I want to keep that one as it is, but the way you showed me the solution forces me to always write \proof{stuff here} in a manner of speaking, I'd like to perhaps define proofname instead so that \proof always writes "Proof" while "proofname" I get to choose what to write in it. Hopefully this clarifies my request.